# Error while making autocalling anonymous function in javascript

Tags: javascript, anonymous-function

I don't know why this is giving me an error when reaching the anonymous function. I found that if that is located at the top of the .js file, it doesn't happen. I can't see why this happens as nothing needs to be read from inside that function that may not yet be read... Any solutions?

```js
function animate_get(selector) {
  var obj = new anim_object(element);
  return obj;
}

function anim_object(element) {}
anim_object.prototype.animate = function(params) {}

(function() {
  alert("yes!");
})()
```

The error shown is: Uncaught TypeError: (intermediate value)(...) is not a function(…)

Strangly it doesn't appear when located at the top (copy-pasted, what makes me think it is correctly written).

Comment: try `anim_object.prototype.animate = function(params) {};` (with trailing semi)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function animate_get(selector) {
  var obj = new anim_object(element);
  return obj;
}

function anim_object(element) {}
anim_object.prototype.animate = function(params) {}; // <=== ; added

(function() {
  alert("yes!");
})()
```

this is why IFFE's are often written like so

```
;(function() {
  alert("yes!");
})()
```

this is also why I'm of the school of thought that ; aren't as optional as the loose early specification of the javascript language allows

I jshint/jslint my code, and place ; where they suggest

then, things like this don't happen

your code looks like this to the js engine

```
anim_object.prototype.animate = function(params) {} (function() {alert("yes!");})()
```

or, in general

```
a = function(p){}(function() {})()
```

which can be valid syntax if the "right" code is between the sets of {} - eg.

```
var a = function(p){return function(a) { return a+p(); }}(function() {return ' <== value is in the last ()';})()
                   ^------first set of {}---------------^            ^-----------second set of {}-----------^
```

where as

```
function anim_object(element) {} anim_object.prototype.animate = function(params) ...
```

or

```
function a {} b = function(params) ...
```

can not be valid regardless of the contents of {}

Comment: This works! But could you explain me why the semicolon is needed after `(params) { }` but not after `(element){ }`

Comment: @Vandervals: it's needed after the assignment above it, that code itself needs no semi at the bottom...